# D-Link DGE-530T PCIe card installation

Tags: drivers, ethernet, pci, d-link

Do I need to install a driver for a [D-Link DGE-530T PCIe card](https://www.dlink.com/en/products/dge-530t-gigabit-desktop-pci-adapter)? I plugged in the card ([support link](https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DGE-530T)) and restarted Ubuntu.

1) Do I really need to install a driver for it or there is native support already?
2) How can I check if the hardware is ready to use?

Comment: There are four different releases of that card with individual drivers, so please go to https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DGE-530T and follow the instructions  to determin if you have the A, B, C, or D release of the card; then, click [edit] and let us know which you have. Please do not click Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: You could look at the output of `dmesg` -- look for something related to your card there, then you may get a hint about its status.

Comment: There is support for it in RedHat, so there may be kernel support for it in Ubuntu, but the specs at D-Link's website don't tell us what's on the card, so here are some tests:  1) Plug in an Ethernet cable; what lights appear? 2) With Ubuntu booted and the card connected, what happens when you ping 8.8.8.8 ? 3) If you get a reply without error, run https://sourceforge.net/speedtest/ 4) Report the results as above.

Comment: Hi, when I run "sudo lshw -class network -short" on the terminal, it shows both network cards. The buildin mother board network card and also additional D-Link card. But when I connect the network cable to the D-Link card, the Ubuntu does not logged in. Any idea how to fix it ?